# Is there a PowerShell script that will stop syncing specific OneDrive for Business folders?

Tags: powershell, onedrive

We have a user that regrets sharing a OneDrive folder.  It was easy enough for them to remove people from the shared folder, but at this point the folder he shared has already been sync'd, so the recipient still has sync'd data on the laptop regardless of the current permission on the shared folder.

Stopping sync of specific OneDrive folders is pretty simple through the OneDrive interface, but is there a way to do it through Powershell?

The user who HAD access to the OneDrive folder would be alright stopping syncing on their own but I may want to push this through Kaseya and use it everytime someone "regrets" sharing out a folder.

Comment: SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)